# How to determine groups of interconnected nodes in a two-dimensional array (graph)?

Tags: c#, arrays, machine-learning, graph-theory

I have a program that compares objects by their properties and then converts it all in a two dimensional array (or a matrix) with values being percentages (1 means 100% similar, 0 means completely different, anything in between is % of similarity).
After that I convert all of it to 1's and 0's to create a map of connections or what's called an adjacency matrix in graph theory which represents nodes that are connected to one another.
[Here's what my situation looks like in terms of graph/matrix/array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvBtJ.png)

It's clear from the image that there are 4 distinct groups of elements: **a1** through **a5** are all linked together and form first group, **b1-b2-b3** form another group of elements, **b4 and b6** are a third group of just two elements and **b5** forms it's own fourth group because it isn't connected to anybody else.

I have the same array in my code. My question is how can I determine which elements belong to the same group or how to group them and store the information about them somewhere else? (be it the index of the element, the value or something else).
I also need to make sure that I don't have repeating groups, so for example elements **b4 and b6** shouldn't form group **b4-b6** and group **b6-b4**, only one of those groups should be present.

Here's part of my code where I tried to implement it by creating new array of strings (and I tried integer too, but it couldn't store the index [0,0] properly, it just stores 0), but this method still doesn't solve the issue of repeating groups or how to identify and pull them out of this array. This method can only correctly identify connections. [Output of this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSUfE.png)

```
        public static string[,] CreateConnectionsMap(double[,] arr)
    {
        string[,] newArr = new string[arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1)];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (arr[i, j] != 0 && arr[i, j] == arr[j, i])
                {
                    newArr[i, j] = $"{i}|{j}";
                }
                else newArr[i, j] = "0";
            }
        }
        return newArr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you're trying to do clustering using a pairwise distance.
The most immediate solution that comes to my mind is to use the agglomerative clustering algorithm.

[This library](https://github.com/pedrodbs/Aglomera) in c# should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, although I'm yet to figure out how to apply this library in my project, but could you also explain or link me to some source on how to install it? I've never made my own dlls in C# and the installation instruction tells me that I'll need to compile it myself after downloading the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    public static int[] CreateConnectionsMap(double[,] arr)
    {
        if (arr.GetLength(0) != arr.GetLength(1))
            throw new ArgumentException("Matrix must be square.");

        int[] groups = new int[arr.GetLength(0)];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            groups[i] = i;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i, j] != 0 && arr[i, j] == arr[j, i])
                {
                    groups[i] = groups[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return groups;
    }
```

Be sure to test it!

Comment: This results in an output "0 0 0 0 0 5 5 5 8 9 8" when I try to write this array in console, is this expected? It seems to be working and it's providing useful result in a sense that all grouped elements have unique value assigned to them, so five elements marked with 0, three elements marked with 5, two elements marked with 8 and one element marked with 9. Thank you for writing this in either case, I'm not quite sure whether this answers my question because I still have to complete the algorithm myself, but I'll get back to it next day once I get some rest.

Comment: That is expected. Yes, it is not complete, I didn't know what the final format of the grouping information should be. Elements in the same group have the same value in the 'groups' array. It might need some additional steps depending on the usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to discover the maximal cliques in the graph.

```
copy graph to work
set flag true
while flag == true
    clear current clique
    while work contains nodes
        if current clique empty
            move arbitrary node from work to current clique
       else
            set flag false
            LOOP w over nodes in work
                 LOOP c over nodes in current clique
                      if w connected to c
                            move w to current clique
                            set flag true
            if flag == false
               break
     add current clique to list of cliques
```

Here is c++ code implementing this algorithm https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder2/blob/dbd6ff06edabd6a6d35d5eb10ed7972dc2d779a6/src/cPathFinder.cpp#L483