# What is the algorithm to find the number of trees in a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Given a list of nodes, e.g.,

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`,

and a list of tuples to indicate the non-directional edges connecting two nodes, e.g.,

`[(2,3), (2,7), (3,7), (4,3), (5,1), (5,6)]`,

**How can I find the number of disjoint trees?**

A tree is a group of notes connected by at least one edge, or an isolated node not connected to any other node.

In my example, there are `3` trees which are:

1. `{2,3,4,7}`
2. `{1,5,6}`
3. `{9}`

I think this is a garden-variety algorithm problem so this question is very likely a duplicate. However I just couldn't find a solution online. Perhaps I am not using the right term to search.

Comment: Search on clique

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69089951/16582

Comment: You're looking for connected [components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of a grpah.

Comment: @ravenspoint The examples don't seem to be complete graphs.

Comment: Not sure, what your understanding of a *tree* is (maybe you mean just connected components) but`{2,3,4,7}` is not a tree, because 3 and 7 each have two parents, whereas 2 and 4 have none, which contradicts my understanding of a *tree* And what about node 8, which is a tree for itself.

Comment: Thanks, @beaker and @derpirscher! I knew I shouldn't call it a tree because the nodes have no parent-child relationship. I tried a few other terms like paths or clusters but they didn't lead me to the correct reference. "Component" it is!

Comment: You can also use the DFS algorithm to find the connected components.

Comment: Why is {8} not counted as a disconnected component?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Credits to @beaker and @derpirscher. I posted some links below and closing this question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)

https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/discuss/516491/Java-Union-Find-DFS-BFS-Solutions-Complexity-Explain-Clean-code

Comment: This is a essentially a link-only answer (not a  good thing).

Comment: Furthermore, the content behind the second link is only accessible to premium-subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the disjoint trees are not necessarily *trees*. They could have cycles. They are generally called [components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

One of the ways to solve this is to use the concept of [Disjoint Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets).

Your language environment may have an implementation of disjoint sets natively or as a library, but here is an implementation of Disjoint Set in Python:

```py
# Implementation of Union-Find (Disjoint Set)
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = self
        self.rank = 0

    def find(self):
        if self.parent.parent != self.parent:
            self.parent = self.parent.find()
        return self.parent

    def union(self, other):
        node = self.find()
        other = other.find()
        if node == other:
            return True # was already in same set
        if node.rank > other.rank:
            node, other = other, node
        node.parent = other
        other.rank = max(other.rank, node.rank + 1)
        return False # was not in same set, but now is
```

So the above is generic, not specifically related to your graph problem. Now to use it for your graph, we create a `Node` instance for each graph node, and call `union` to indicate that connected nodes belong to the same graph-component:

```py
def count_components(nodeids, edges):
    # Create dictionary of nodes, keyed by their IDs
    nodes = {
        nodeid: Node() for nodeid in nodeids
    }
    # All connected nodes belong to the same disjoined set:
    for a, b in edges:
        nodes[a].union(nodes[b])
    # Count distinct roots to which each node links
    return len(set(node.find() for node in nodes.values()))
```

We can run it for your example graph as follows:

```py
vertices = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
edges = [(2,3), (2,7), (3,7), (4,3), (5,1), (5,6)]
print(count_components(vertices, edges))  # 4
```

This prints 4 because of these identified disjoint sets:

```py
{2,3,4,7}
{1,5,6}
{8}
{9}
```